# EF Core 6.0 Insert Failure: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am using

- SQL Server 2019 Express
- Visual Studio 2022
- EF Core 6.0
- .Net Core 6.0

My database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [temp].[REGISTRATION]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [companyname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [middlename] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [genderid] [int] NULL,
    [email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [whatsappno] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [username] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [encypass] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)
```

Model class:

```
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("companyname")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Companyname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("firstname")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Column("middlename")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("lastname")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Column("genderid")]
    public int? Genderid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("email")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("phone")]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Column("whatsappno")]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Whatsappno { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("username")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("encypass")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Encypass { get; set; }
```

API Post Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Registration>> PostRegistration(Registration registration)
{
    _context.Registrations.Add(registration);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetRegistration", new { id = registration.Id }, registration);
}
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "companyname": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "genderid": 0,
    "email": "string",
    "phone": "string",
    "whatsappno": "string",
    "username": "string",
    "encypass": "string"
}
```

Error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions

After inserting one row manually in the SQL Server table with an `INSERT INTO` query, the code (HTTPPost) executes properly.

I also used:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

but it still throws the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check SQL Server log files for errors?

Comment: Is `Registration ` a record type? I'm not sure there's enough information in the question to answer the question definitively.

Comment: are you posting the exact body you have pasted here, with those exact values? (is the id actually 0 when you post the request?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: For @jdweng : No I did not checked the log.

Comment: @AndyG: Model class name Registration.

Comment: @fbede: id is 0 because it is a identity column